# How to swap two keys in a map

Tags: java, dictionary, key, swap

Is there a way to swap two keys in a map in Java?

ex. for list there is `Collections.swap(ArrayList,1,2);`

Answer (score 6):

You can use this one liner:

```
map.put('a', map.put('b', map.get('a')));
```

Comment: just to clarify this works because map.put() returns the previous value, so when you put the new value of 'b', the return would be the old value, which is then put in 'a'.  Hence the swap.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle boundary cases, like one of the keys not actually being in the map, you can do something like this:

```
public static <K,V> void swap(Map<K, V> map, K k1, K k2) {
    if (map.containsKey(k1)){
        if (map.containsKey(k2)){
            map.put(k1, map.put(k2, map.get(k1)));
        } else {
            map.put(k2, map.remove(k1));
        }
    } else if (map.containsKey(k2)){
        map.put(k1, map.remove(k2));
    }
}
```

Otherwise, use the on-liner in Abdullah Jibaly's answer.